# Why on every play jmeter gives different results for same data?

Tags: jmeter

Why on every play jmeter gives different results for same data? Its difficult to extract actual results for load testing because every time we have different result

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: Like if i have 50 threads to hit a url, and I play 3 times test plan, there are 3 different results shown on Graphs i.e may be first time 10 passes 40 fails, second time 20 passes, so how can we extract actual result